# Identify the slow hop when downloading video

Tags: networking, command-line

I'm downloading a video as follows

```
$ youtube-dl url_to_video
```

The download of the file is very slow

`33.1% of 301.31MiB at 19.75KiB/s ETA 02:54:03`

It was usually faster.

Could you identify with command-line tools where is the bottleneck (the hop where the speed rapidly slows down)? The command-line tool, should be able to display the slow-down in speed in hop X in contrast to hop X+1.

Comment: IMHO the analysis is possible only if you had an access to all intermediate hops or at least to the hop where the slowdown occurs.

Comment: Try ``mtr(8)``.

Comment: @phg `mtr` doesn't appear to solve the problem (there was an answer here last week suggesting `mtr`, but the owner has deleted it). If you think it does, please do post an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the tools `timeout`, `traceroute` and `bing` installed this script may help.

What this does is to iterate down a `traceroute` listing, and compare the packet speed to the "current" host with the packet speed of the previous host. This difference (if any) is then reported to the user.

It requires a target hostname. Since you're using `youtube-dl` you need to get that to tell you the hostname of the server delivering the video. Here is an example of usage to derive the hostname:

```
youtube-dl --get-url --simulate 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQZlqeUBbck' 2>/dev/null |
    cut -d/ -f3
```

For me, that gets me the hostname `r7---sn-aiglln76.googlevideo.com`. With that you can run the script (below). It takes a little while to run, and for the first minute or so you may get no output at all.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
target="$1"    # Hostname
test -z "$target" && read -p "Target destination: " target

phop=0 first=y
timeout 90 traceroute "$target" |
    awk '$1+0' |
    while read hop rhost rip junk
    do
        test "$rhost" == '*' && continue
        rip="${rip//[()]/}"

        # Is the host reachable?
        ping -q -c1 -w4 "$rip" >/dev/null 2>&1 || continue

        if test -n "$rhost" -a -n "$phost"
        then
            test -n "$first" && { printf "Hops\tRoute\n"; first=; }

            # Test the link speed between these two hosts
            bing=$(
                bing -c1 -e20 "$pip" "$rip" 2>/dev/null |
                tail -1 |
                awk '!/zero/ {print $2}'
            )

            # Report any useful result
            printf "%2d-%2d\t%s (%s) to %s (%s): %s\n" "$phop" "$rhop" "$phost" "$pip" "$rhost" "$rip" "${bing:-no measured difference}"
        fi

        # Save the current host for the next hop comparison
        phop="$rhop" phost="$rhost" pip="$rip"
    done
```

Some output from a test run in the UK to a remote office:

```
Hops    Route
 1- 4   10.20.1.254 (10.20.1.254) to aaa.obscured (): no measured difference
 4- 5   be200.asr01.thn.as20860.net (62.128.207.218) to 195.66.227.42 (195.66.227.42): no measured difference
 5- 6   195.66.227.42 (195.66.227.42) to core3-hu0-1-0-5.faraday.ukcore.bt.net (62.172.103.132): no measured difference
 6- 7   core3-hu0-1-0-5.faraday.ukcore.bt.net (62.172.103.132) to 195.99.127.60 (195.99.127.60): no measured difference
 7- 8   195.99.127.60 (195.99.127.60) to acc1-10gige-0-2-0-0.bm.21cn-ipp.bt.net (109.159.248.25): 512.000Mbps
 8- 9   acc1-10gige-0-2-0-0.bm.21cn-ipp.bt.net (109.159.248.25) to 109.159.248.99 (109.159.248.99): no measured difference
 9-14   109.159.248.99 (109.159.248.99) to bbb.obscured (): 717.589Kbps
```

From this is can be seen that my traffic appears to have a big slow down between 9 and 14, where we're dropped down to a typical ADSL upstream.

I should point out that `bing` cannot measure a speed difference between two remote points if their connection speed exceeds your available connection to those points. My connection is 512Mbps so I can't measure most of the carrier links.

Comment: I tried to use the script, but...
`bash test_youtube.bash https://youtu.be/code
https://youtu.be/code: Name or service not known
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `https://youtu.be/code' on position 1 (argc 1)` Are there some restrictions on the input?